Is finding a fractinal subgraph satisfying degree constriant NP-hard?
I would like to ask if the following problem would be NP-hard.
Given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ and an integer $d$, we are required to determine whether there exists a subset $S \subseteq V$ such that, in the subgraph $G_S= (S, E_S)$ induced by $S$, there exists a fractional subgraph of $E_S$, $f: E_S \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that

for any vertex $s\in S$, $\sum_{(j, s) \in E_S} f((j,s)) = \sum_{(s, j) \in E_S} f((s, j)) = d$.

It is also encouraged if there are any thoughts on the undirected version, which means the total fraction of every vertex in $S$ is exactly equal to $d$. In other words, we need to determine whether there exists a subset $S\subseteq V$ such that there is a $d$-fractional-regular graph on it.
Thanks a lot!
Thanks @caduk, for pointing out a simplification of the statement!

Even for directed graphs, we need exactly $d$ units of flow at each vertex of $d$, since the total flow produced must be equal to the total flow consumed, and vertices of $S$ can only consume flow.

Hi caduk, thanks for the comment! Exactly! I took a deep thought and realized what you are saying is correct. Summing all the out-degrees should be equal to the sum of in-degrees, which means all inequalities should be turned into equalities. I would modify the statement of the problem. Thanks a lot!
